# Required license is missing: Runtime Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am getting this error

> Required license is missing: Runtime

I have checked datafolder path

```
 <sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\Path\Data" />
```

and license file settings

```
  <setting name="LicenseFile" value="$(dataFolder)/license.xml" />
```

also checked permission all is correct but still it is giving error.

Comment: Can you check using yourhostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx if the LicenseFile value is correct ? Maybe is overriden from a patch file.

Comment: I am not able to see config file because it is giving same error "Required license is missing: Runtime Sitecore"

Comment: Search for all `dataFolder` occurences in your `App_config\include` folder

Comment: Partner License?  They expire once a year.

Comment: No, It is not expired.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm at this spot right now.

Comment: @Swati Gupta Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904486/how-can-i-add-defer-attribute-in-the-sitecore-foundation-frameworks-min-js

Answer (score 16):

The most likely cause is a patch file in the include folder that is changing your path. Sometimes this is called "DataFolder.config" and may have the default path set in it, which will overwrite the setting value you might have in another patch config or in the Web.config file.

There are some tools that let you track down config settings without having a working Sitecore instance. I would try out the Config Builder (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_ConfigBuilder.aspx) which should be able to load up all your config settings and help you track down the problem.

Comment: Full path for reference: `\App_Config\Include\DataFolder.config`

Answer (score 6):

I know it is a pretty late to answer, but for folks who end up here - this might be helpful. 
There could be couple of reasons why you get this error. Since OP had already mentioned that his license file has not expired -  Another viable reason is

The datafolder path is wrong. the first line of the Sitecore.config line defines the datafolder path. For eg: something like this:

```
 <sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sitecoredev\Data\"/>
```

if you have any developer create a different instance name or folder and checks it in, it will not find the path and hence you will get this error.

Comment: This was my problem, thank you. Never would have thought to look for this. What a mess!

Answer (score 4):

Check if the licence file has expired:

> Confirm that the expiration date in the licenses has not been reached or passed.  Open the license.xml file with a text editor and search for “expires”; find the line corresponding to the “20060319”.  If the date has been reached or passed (for instance, if it is March 19, 2006 or later), the license will not work; obtain an updated license.

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Troubleshooting/License%20Issues.aspx

Comment: If it hadn't expired, it definitely has by now :)

Comment: I got this error and it was because the license was expired.  I think the authors should have said as much in the exception's message, but fortunately, there's stackoverflow.com to compensate.

Comment: just a note on this answer, i searched for "expiration" rather than "expires", not sure if this was changed from previous sitecore versions or not but this is what i found in sitecore 10 :)

Answer (score 3):

I have installed 8.2 update 5 on my local machine. The default installation adds a folder called 'zzz' in App_config/include folder and creates DataFolder.config in that folder and references the data folder name from that config file. My publish overwrote/deleted that folder and i got the error 'Required license is missing: Runtime Sitecore'.

Adding that folder 'zzz' from my backup site resolved that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed that even if after fixing the path you may still see this error. Once you fix path with valid license, **DON'T forget to reset IIS/ Apppool**.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the possibilities for the error.

1. **Verify if the license file is present** - You can check this in the default data directory of the Sitecore installation path. If the file is not there add it here and restart the IIS.
2. **The path of the License file is wrong** - The default path of the Sitecore license file will be specified in the “web.config,” and if you are using the Sitecore 8+ version, then verify Sitecore.config file(App_config/Sitecore.config) where LicenseFile settings are provided
3. **Overriding the License file path** - If you are using any Patch files or thrid-party libraries like brainjocks then make sure the patch file is not overriding the default path.
4. **License expired** - Don't forget the check if you provided license is been still active or expired. You can do this by opening the license.xml in editor and verifying the field "**expiry**" and the date.

**Config File settings**

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/data" />
<setting name="LicenseFile" value="$(dataFolder)/license.xml" />
```

Source - [Sitecore Required license is missing: Runtime [Solved]](https://itsmycode.com/sitecore-required-license-is-missing-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

Something to watch out for: I had multiple config files for different environments (e.g. DataFolder.QA.config, DataFolder.Live.config) which were overriding my DataFolder.config with values that were incorrect for my local environment. Deleting the unneeded environment configs got this working.

Answer (score 0):

go to "/app_config/sitecore.config" search for "LicenseFile" update the value to hold an absolute path to your sitecore license

Answer (score -4):

if you have doubt whether sitecore is looking into correct place, check out  `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page. this is what sitecore really uses after combining all configurations. You can chekc both `<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="C:\Path\Data" />` and `<setting name="LicenseFile" value="$(dataFolder)/license.xml" />` there. Of course this page only shows `<sitecore>...</sitecore>` part of configuration.

Also make sure that `NETWORK SERVICE` account or `<your IIS app pool name here>` account (depending on which Identity is bound to your App Pool instance) has full access to `Data` folder and also `App_Data` subfolder inside webroot, just to rule out any read/write access issue

Comment: You can not call /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx when the Licence file is missing. You get the same error then.